# caching text similar to iMessage App

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I was wondering how to implement the caching of strings in UITextView or UITextField the same way it is done in iMessage app, i.e even if you quit the app and come back to it, although the message hasn't been sent yet, it is still there in the text field. e.g Would NSCache as a global singleton be a viable choice for this?

Comment: that is up to you how you'd like to save it or restore it; user defaults; serializable objects; etc... it is too broad and mostly based on personal opinion as well, plus it depends on the actual project's environment too.

Comment: @holex ok I think NSUserDefaults was what I was looking for.